# Django keyerror from built in form

Tags: django, forms, keyerror

I'm trying to create a simple form in order to add users. Im using the built in form generation UserCreationForm(). I found example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287485/taking-user-input-to-create-users-in-django) that I used.

here is my view:

```
def user_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
            login(new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('main.html')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm() 

    return render(request, 'main/user_add_djDefault.html', {'form': form.as_p()})
```

The Form is genereated correctly, but when I enter data and submit it then:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 'password1' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

the error happens here:

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data)
```

Since the form creation and validation is based on the same model I wonder where this error comes from ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because `create_user` expects a parameter called `password` and **NOT** `password1` that is used in `UserCreationForm`.

Notice the signature for `create_user`:

```
create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields)
```

You can try calling the method like this:

```
cd = form.cleaned_data
User.objects.create_user(
    username=cd.get('username'),
    password=cd.get('password1'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you Derek. I thought everything would (magically) fit together :) but these few extra steps are no problem anyway ...